# Django / Python (PEP 8): If I want to name a model class called Property. Should I leave it as Property or Property_?

Tags: python, django, django-models, pep8

I know that `property()` is a built-in function in Python, but I want to name a model class as `Property`. Something simple like this:

```
class Property(models.Model):
    name             = models.CharField(max_length=135)
    owner            = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='properties_from_owner')
    address_line_one = models.CharField(max_length=135)
    address_line_two = models.CharField(max_length=135, blank=True)
    city             = models.CharField(max_length=135)
    state            = models.CharField(max_length=135)
    zip_code         = models.CharField(max_length=135)
```

Should I call the class `Property` or `Property_`? Now I know Python is case-sensitive, but the reason I ask is because in Django the `Property` model class is identified as `myapp.property`.

In other models that relates to `Property` I added a `_` to the fields like this

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user      = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='userprofile_from_user')
    property_ = models.ForeignKey(Property, related_name='userprofiles_from_property')
```

Comment: `property` is built-in function not a keyword.

Comment: FWIW: Classes more or less have their own namespace. To reference `property` you'll always have to use something like `UserProfile.property` or `self.property`, neither of which will clash with the built-in `property`. Generally you're safe to use any name you like inside a class (with the exception of true keywords like `def`, `class` etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`property` is not a keyword but a function. You could overwrite it if you want (while making sure you don't mix up the two later in the file.

In a situation where no mix-up is possible, I see no reason not to do it.

Comment: Even if you are planning to use underscores to differentiate from keywords/functions etc, just ensure you don't use double underscores, Django gets confused.